# Are protobuf Serialize/Parse operations bijective?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am writing an application that computes and verifies signatures from protobuf structure. It is computed like `sign(protobuf_message.SerializeAsString())`.
Can I be sure, that identical `protobuf_message` will be serialized identically (with different versions of the library (but using only proto2 encoding), on different computers, in different conditions) and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) precisely defines binary message format.

In particular, it says:

> While you can use field numbers in any order in a .proto, when a message is serialized **its known fields should be written sequentially by field number, as in the provided C++, Java, and Python serialization code**. This allows parsing code to use optimizations that rely on field numbers being in sequence. However, protocol buffer parsers must be able to parse fields in any order, as not all messages are created by simply serializing an object – for instance, it's sometimes useful to merge two messages by simply concatenating them.

So as long as you don't produce new messages by concatenating other messages, and use serialization code provided by the protobuf library itself, the serialized messages should be identical. If you are using some third-party protobuf binding (e.g for C#) you should check if it conforms with the recommendation above.

Comment: Note that with some old versions of protobuf library (e.g. before packed arrays), the serialization has been slightly different. But for anything >= protobuf 2.4 it should be identical. I have myself a test case that verifies the identical encoding as a part of testing nanopb.

Comment: There is a big caveat in the above-quoted paragraph: it only applies to _known_ fields. If the protobuf contains any _unknown_ fields (e.g. because it was written by a newer version of the application, and is now being processed in an older version), those fields are appended to the end in an arbitrary order (since properly merging them would have been expensive). proto3 removes unknown fields, but this is worse: dropping the unknown fields obviously changes the canonical encoding. So basically you can never add new fields to your proto if you care about signatures/canonicalization. :/

Comment: @jpa Packed arrays don't affect serialization unless you add the `[packed=true]` annotation to a field, and then the always affect it, so this only affects canonicalization in that changing the option will change the canonical form. As long as the protobuf definition hasn't changed, there should be no difference in serialization with different versions of protobufs going back long before the open source release.